# Mapping private subnet hostnames to localhost with the same hostname and ports

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel, private-network

**Background:**

We currently have a development lab on AWS. Our project has a lot of microservices. For development/debugging developers usually would run one microservice on their laptop and connect to the rest of the services to the lab, since it is not feasible to have all necessary microservices running on the same laptop.

If it's only one service, developers would create an SSH tunnel and it will be mapped to some random port on localhost. But it quickly becomes tedious when there are several services to connect to and they have to manually create tunnels for each of them and change the configuration from hostnames to localhost and port.

**Goal:**

All of the microservices are running on some EC2 instance which has a hostname like `xyz-service001`. I want to find out a way to build a permanent script or set of commands so that all these services can directly be accessible on developers' laptop using the same hostname and ports.

Like running `http://xyz-service001:8080` should work instead of building a tunnel and accessing like this: `http://localhost:10045`.

In our current setup, we use a bastion server (jumphost) to create SSH tunnel to the EC2 instances in the private subnet.

I would like to know if anyone has attempted to do the above or in general how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Create a VPN from where the developers sit,
2. Create a Route 53 Private Hosted Zone,
3. Route 53 Resolver to forward requests for the names you create on the Private Hosted Zone